# When should we use the Styled Components instead of regular components in React?

Tags: reactjs

When should we use the Styled Components instead of regular components in React?

I was creating a new component in react then i came across the concept of Styled Components and  got confused about when should i use it exactly, instead of regular react component

Comment: When you want to style the components. It's a library that let you style the components https://styled-components.com/

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to personal preference in terms of how you want to write styles for your app's components. If you find using .css imports to be annoying and prefer writing inline styles, then you may want to considering using [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) library.

Using a library like this also tends to shift you more towards the reusable-components mindset.